# User input, don't allow the same input twice

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to ask a user for an input but I don't want the user to be able to input the same number twice. Here is what I was trying

```
            g1 = iBox.getInteger("Enter your 1st number");
            g2 = iBox.getInteger("Enter your 2nd number");
                if(g1 == g2){
                    g2 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
            g3 = iBox.getInteger("Enter your 3rd number");
                if(g3 == g1){
                    g3 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
                else if(g3 == g2){
                    g3 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
            g4 = iBox.getInteger("Enter your 4th number");
                if(g4 == g1){
                    g4 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
                else if(g4 == g2){
                    g4 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
                else if(g4 == g3){
                    g4 =iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
                }
            oBox.print(" " + g1 + " " + g2 + " " + g3 + " " + g4 + " ");
```

Comment: There is no question here.
Of what type is `iBox`?

Comment: Can we get some more information? What exceptions (if any) are being thrown? Presumably you are experiencing unexpected behavior. Could you detail this behavior? I'm more than happy to help; I just need to know what isn't working with your code (because, at first glance, it looks pretty good)

Comment: When I input "1" into the InputBox g1 and then "1" into the second InputBox g2, it tells me already used, then I put "1" in g2 again it accepts the value. I don't want the inputbox to be able to take in a value that has already been used.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a loop and a set.
Pseudocode:

```
let S be the set of used numbers(or array, if order is important)
clear contents of S
for I = 1 to N, where N is the number of numbers you want to get
    int g = iBox.getInteger("Enter Ith number");
    while(S.contains(g))
        g = iBox.getInteger("Number used, please re-enter");
    Add g into S.
```

Answer (score 1):

- Take an `ArrayList`
- Scan the value from User , parse , validate add to `ArrayList`
- Do `contains()` to check if it is already there in the `list`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing your previous input in a `List` or some sort of collection. Then you can use the `.contains(Object o)` method to see if the collection already contains the specific value.

This will allow you to extend your application beyond a fixed number of inputs.

[Collection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)